# Query table datatype from function in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, function, plsql, blob

colleagues

I have a problem with table function in Oracle.

More specifically, I have a function that converts BLOB into table of varchar2.

```
create type string_array is table of varchar2(255);

create or replace function blob_to_strings(p_blb in BLOB) return string_array as
begin
-- some processing here
end;
```

Also I have table containing BLOBS I need to work with.

```
create table my_blobs (id number, data blob)
```

Now, having `id` in `my_blobs` table, I want to query result of convert function. Something like

```
select t.* from table(blob_to_strings(b.data)) t, my_blobs b where b.id = 123;
```

(I know this is incorrect, just showing what I need)
This query expectedly returns `b.data: invalid identifier` as you can't access other table columns inside `from` section.

I understand how to do it in PL/SQL running 2 queries, but really need to do it in SQL.

Can anybody help me?
Thank you in advance.

**UPD:** I tried following:

```
select * from table(select blob_to_strings(b.data) from my_blobs b where b.id = 123);
```

*Result:* ORA-00902: invalid datatype

Any other ideas?

Comment: What issues do you get when you run the above select statement? Also, "convert" is a bad name for a function as it is also an Oracle keyword. I would suggest renaming as something like "blob_to_string_array" - something more meaningful. Once you do that, your query should probably work, once you update the function name.

Comment: Well, first of all, you can't reference table field in `from` section. So in this query I receive `b.data: Invalid identifier` as expected.
And yes - my function is called another way, `convert` is used for example only - I will edit post to avoid misunderstanding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possibly the issue with your original query was that you had the table name coming after the attempt to select from the array (`from table(blob_to_strings(b.data)) t, my_blobs b`). In other words, you were trying to select from something that hadn't yet been declared. Switch the order of the items in the from clause, and it should work.

Here's a test case that I knocked up to demonstrate (I used CLOBs since we're apparently dealing with text; I'm not sure why you're using BLOBs?):

```
create table t1 (id number,
                 clob_col clob);

insert into t1 values (1, 'abcd');
insert into t1 values (2, 'efg');

commit;

create type string_array is table of varchar2(255);

create or replace function clob_to_str_tab (p_clob in clob)
return string_array
is
  v_str_arr string_array := string_array();
begin
  for i in 1.. length(p_clob)
  loop
    v_str_arr.extend;
    v_str_arr(i) := substr(p_clob, i, 1);
  end loop;

  return v_str_arr;
end;
/

select t1.id,
       t2.column_value res
from   table(clob_to_str_tab(t1.clob_col)) t2,
       t1;

ORA-00904: "T1"."CLOB_COL": invalid identifier

select t1.id,
       t2.column_value res
from   t1,
       table(clob_to_str_tab(t1.clob_col)) t2;

        ID RES
---------- ---
         1 a  
         1 b  
         1 c  
         1 d  
         2 e  
         2 f  
         2 g
```

Comment: Great thanks for your answer - that helped me a lot!
Actually my problem was not only in tables order but rather in `string_array` type. This type was declared in package and `blob_to_str` function also was in same package. So as I understood SQL just couldn't find the type returned by function.

Can I do something to make SQL understand this type without creating global type for everybody?

Comment: in 11g and prior, you need to create the type at a schema level, rather than just in PL/SQL. I believe that it might be possible in 12c, but I've not used that yet.

Comment: That was really not trivial to find a gap.
Big thanks once again!

Answer (score -1):

You can achieve this with Oracle's **PIPE ROW** statement

See:  [Pipelined Table Functions](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/pipelined-table-functions)

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand you. I know how to create function that returns table, but the problem here is that I need to join this function to other database table and pass field from this table to function parameter.